# structures within structures in matlab

Tags: matlab, data-structures, struct

```
s(1) = struct('a', 2, 'b', 3)
s(1).c(1) = struct('x',4, 'y',5);
s(1).c(2) = struct('x',6, 'y',7);
s(1).c(3) = struct('x',8, 'y',9);
```

I get an error when I try this

```
s(2) = struct('a', 10, 'b', 11)

Subscripted assignment between dissimilar structures.
```

I'm looking for a way to create `c(1)`, `c(2)` and `c(3)` sub-fields directly when I'm creating `s(1)`, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can create your structure with `c(1)`, `c(2)`, and `c(3)` as follows,

```
s(1) = struct('a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', [struct('x', 4, 'y', 5) struct('x', 6, 'y', 7) struct('x', 8, 'y', 9)])
```

If you create `s(2)` the fields need to match those present in `s(1)`. You can, however, leave `c` empty in `s(2)` if desired.

```
s(2) = struct('a', 10, 'b', 11, 'c', struct)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the struct array using indexing, without assigning each of the fields, like so:

```
s(2).a = 10;
s(2).b = 11;
```

In this case, the `c` field remains empty (i.e. `[]`). There is no need for the fields to have the same types, if `s(1).c` is a struct, then `s(2).c` can be an array or a string or whatever you want.

With `deal` you can turn this into a one-liner:

```
[ s(2).a , s(2).b ] = deal( 10 , 11 );
```

---

To create all the elements of the struct `s(1).c` in one go, you can use the following syntax for `struct`:

```
s(1).c = struct('x',{4,6,8}, 'y',{5,7,9});
```

The data fields here is a cell array, where each element of the cell array specifies the value for that field in one of the struct array elements.

Of course you can combine the creation of the whole `c(1)` into one command:

```
s(1) = struct('a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', struct('x',{4,6,8}, 'y',{5,7,9}));
```

In a similar way, you can build up the creation of both `s(1)` and `s(2)` in one go:

```
s = struct('a', {2,10}, 'b', {3,11}, 'c', {struct('x',{4,6,8}, 'y',{5,7,9}),[]});
```

...but this gets increasingly cumbersome to write in a single line of code. Use ellipses to make it more readable:

```
s = struct('a',{ 2,                                10 }, ...
           'b',{ 3,                                11 }, ...
           'c',{ struct('x',{4,6,8}, 'y',{5,7,9}), [] });
```